# Verbose logging in Kubernetes deployment file

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Iam new to Kubernetes , i want to know what does 'V' in the following mean ?

```
 spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - -v=9
```

It seems to me it denotes verbose logging , is there any documentation for the same regarding the various levels of logging avbl like what values that arg v can take ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes uses [glog](https://github.com/golang/glog). The available values are 1-4, as denoted in [this doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/logging.md)

Comment: In the code mentioned above value is 9 , any thoughts on that?

Comment: It depends on the application, what app is it?

Comment: The app is nginx-ingress  .

Comment: nginx-ingress also uses glog. so -v=9 will just default to 4. see here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Glog&type=